# Single-boot and drive caddy

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

I just installed 16.04 LTS on my laptop.
Right now, I have two HD drive. 
The main one (sda), where I have installed Ubuntu. And the other one (in the drive caddy), just for data storage (sdc).

I succesfully installed Ubuntu, but at startup grub gave me a
`error: no such device ... grub rescue>` 
error.

Two years ago (installing 14.04) the solution has been to install the bootloader on the caddy drive (sdc). This way the laptop boots regularly, but I cannot change anymore the hd drive in the caddy.
As I'd like to use the caddy to swap different hd's for data storage, do you suggest any solution not involving the boot loader on the caddy?

Thanks

Comment: Go into the BIOS / set-up on the laptop (accessible with a key / key combo like F2 during boot), and there you should be able to change the boot order so that the main hard drive is first in the boot order priority.

Comment: The main drive is already the first one in the boot order, and also the only `enabled` as bootable (apart from USB drives). Right now I found, as a solution the following command sequence:  `grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdc update-grub` . Is this possible to do with every HD I put inside the caddy, on time and for all?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with every HDD you put in the caddy. However, I find it somewhat strange that the BIOS does not allow you to boot only from the main hard drive, because it _should_..

Comment: Actually, now I can boot without the hd caddy inserted,too. Would it be appropriate to edit as SOLVED?